# krsort for for arrays with INTs as an index

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array that looks like this:

```
 Array ( [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [1] => 1 )
```

i want to sort the array so the integers are in descending order

```
 Array ( [3] => 2 [2] => 2 [1] => 1 )
```

is there a php function that can do that, i tried krsort, but i think that only works on strings as all it outputted "1".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

krsort is right but it *changes* the array (pass by reference), not returns a new one.

```
krsort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`krsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php). Sorts an array by key in reverse order.

```
krsort($array);
```

Check out more information on [sorting arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 0):

> all it outputted "1".

Because you called it as:

```
$newarr = krsort($myarr);
```

and `krsort()` returns true/false on success/failure. The array is sorted in-place and is still referenced by $myarr.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print_r($arr);
krsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC)
print_r($arr);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$age=array("35","37","43");
print_r($age); 

krsort($age,1);
print_r($age);
```

visit here for more help : - http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_krsort.asp